# Relative increase between two pairs of samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, bootstrap, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Consider the following samples from four distributions:

$a = \{20, 2, 200\} \qquad\qquad c = \{1, 10, 100\}$

$b = \{22, 2.2, 220\} \qquad\quad\:\,d = \{1.2, 12, 120\}$

I would like to say that the relative increase from $a$ to $b$ is significantly less than the relative increase from $c$ to $d$.

---

If the samples are assumed to be paired, with the $n$th element of $a$ corresponding to the $n$th element of $b$, this can be done with a Mann-Whitney U test on the element-wise ratios of the distributions:

$\frac{b}{a} = \{1.1, 1.1, 1.1\}$ vs $\frac{d}{c} = \{1.2, 1.2, 1.2\}$

giving a p-value of 0.02 (tending towards 0 with larger samples).

---

But what if the samples are not assumed to be paired, or have different sizes?  A 'ratio bootstrapping' test could be used instead: randomly select numbers $a_i$, $b_j$, $c_k$, $d_l$ with replacement from each distribution and see how often $b_j / a_i < d_l / c_k$.

For this example, 31 of the 81 possible selections have $b_j / a_i > d_l / c_k$, giving a p-value of $\frac{31}{81} \approx 0.38$.  Ratio bootstrapping is inconclusive here because the variance within each distribution is larger than the variability (e.g. difference in means or medians) between the pairs of distributions.

Is there a statistical test which accomplishes the same thing as ratio bootstrapping, but is insensitive to intra-distribution variance and only focuses on the variability between distributions?

Comment: You seem to be saying "what if the data aren't paired?". If values are positive, you could consider shifts in the mean of the logs, perhaps (since on the log scale the mean difference of pairs and the difference of unpaired means should both estimate the same location difference).

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, paired rather than ordered is a better way of putting it.  Neat idea!  However, if I am only using the mean of the logs of each distribution (4 numbers), how can I get a reliable p-value?

Comment: You compare the means of the logs; that doesn't mean you *only use the means of the logs*. I simply meant compare locations via a standard location test, such as a t-test.

Comment: Alright, but a t-test only compares two distributions.  How are you suggesting using it with four?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. You could look at a specific contrast in ANOVA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comments to an answer:

One possibility is to work on the log-scale (since on the log scale the mean difference of pairs and the difference of unpaired means should both estimate the same location difference).

Since you have quadruplets of observations that share a "position", you could consider either 'pairs of pair-differences' or an ANOVA, with the position as a blocking factor and test a contrast that corresponds to the comparison of ratios. The advantage of the ANOVA approach is that you can do more general things (e.g. treat the positions as a random effect rather than fixed effect, or test other form of hypothesis relatively easily).

Comment: Is it actually valid to use Anova in this situation, when the data are not normally distributed?  Is [nparcomp](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/nparcomp/html/nparcomp.html) with a user-defined contrast matrix applicable here?  Also, if I am correct, this compares medians rather than means, which is preferable for me.

Comment: Note that (i) what's assumed to be normal is the conditional distributions (equivalently, the error term) on the log scale; (ii) ANOVA is still best linear unbiased, so if you're after estimates it still does quite well any time a linear estimator is reasonable; (iii) as far as CIs and tests go, ANOVA is fairly robust to moderate deviation from normality (if the conditional distribution on the log scale is still a problem, you can use permutation/randomization approaches, or the bootstrap, or robust methods); ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... (iv) if the conditional distribution on the log scale is approximately normal you can estimate the mean on the original untransformed scale pretty well by an adjustment (multiply by $\exp(\frac{_1}{^2}\hat{\sigma}^2)$), but if you're interested in the ratio, the adjustment term cancels out (that is, a ratio of means will be the same as a ratio of medians). Even if it's only close to normal, you can derive a similar term as an expansion which will also cancel; (v) if you are prepared to make some other parametric assumption, you may be able to derive what you need. Lots of options...